# Is 'illusion' as viewed in indian philosophy founded on more fundamental concepts or experiences?

Tags: existence, buddhism, eastern-philosophy, hinduism, vedanta

Concerning the concept of illusion of the world of common experience, as found in many systems of Indian philosophy, I am under the impression that it always comes as a "made-up" solution to life's problems, e.g. suffering, impermanence, difficulty in satisfying one's desires. 
So is there a system in which illusion follows from more fundamental concepts, as a *necessary* aspect of the world and not as an "a posteriori" solution to life's problems? 
The question is of course meaningless if its answer can be given only in terms of individual experience not involving logical reasoning.

Comment: The idea of *maya* comes as a consequence of the metaphysical thesis of [non-dualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondualism) derived from Advaita Vedanta, the "transcending" of the subject/object distinction. Advaita is rather cerebral, and its classical defense by Shankara, for example, does not draw on ethical considerations traditionally encountered in Buddhism. It is somewhat similar to metaphysical arguments of Western thinkers like Parmenides and Spinoza, who are also very cerebral, see [Spinoza and Shankara](https://www.pdcnet.org/symposium/content/symposium_2014_0018_0001_0215_0235)

Comment: The use of the word illusion is a misnomer when describing the concept of Maya. A better word is superimposition. There is a good explanation of it from the Advaita non-dualistic position here, under the section titled 'Adhyasa or Superimposition' - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda After reading the suggested text I think that removing ignorance is like doing mathematics, where it's impossible to "see a rope in a snake" i.e. prove false results. Theorems are true forever, embedded in larger truths,as finite numbers are embedded in infinity. And if I understand a proof then the book is useless, I can naturally re-do it myself. Unclear, self-contradictory desires are transformed into well-defined problems seeking answers along luminous ways. But the objection is that life becomes dryly squared down and much of its emotional richness is lost that way.

Comment: The name of Book is: Six Meanings Other Than Illusion, Donald A. Braue https://books.google.at/books/about/M%C4%81y%C4%81_in_Radhakrishnan_s_Thought.html?id=VEbPwuCIdDYC&redir_esc=y

Comment: Sometimes the concept of maya is taken to mean the world is an illusion, but that’s not exactly what Krishna says. According to Him, the material world is very real, but, like a house of mirrors, its purpose is to delude us. In a house of mirrors, the house and the observer are real, but because the mirrors distort reality within the house, the images perceived within it are illusory.
We’re continuously in illusion, or maya. .http://www.krishna.com/escaping-reality-illusion

Comment: See this paper scientifically proving the Indian philosophy of Illusion  : Transpersonal realities or neurophysiological illusions
Charles T. Tart,     https://philpapers.org/rec/TARTRO

Comment: This Book also prove the Indian philosophy of Illusion https://www.amazon.de/Reality-Illusion-Experience-Strauch-2000-03-01/dp/B01K17V0NW

Comment: @Hassan Jolany  Thank you for these useful links.

Answer (score 2):

In Western critical theory (the current evolute of the post-modernist/post-structuralist type thinking), they often harp on the idea of a 'language world': a superimposition of human language and human concepts on the 'natural' world. Their point is that it is this 'language world' that we live in, not the 'natural' world. For example, if I pick up a hammer, no one really doubts that the hammer has all sorts of *natural* properties — mass, structural composition, electromagnetic reactance, etc — but as I rule I am neither interested in nor aware of those properties. I picked this object up because I wanted a 'hammer': a tool that is linguistically defined to have certain uses and functions in *human* terms. We know this because we know that I can substitute a wide range of different objects for this particular hammer, so long as they have the same functional use in the moment. A hammer is a hammer is a hammer, even if the three hammers are *entirely different* in terms of their essential, 'natural' composition and properties.

If we expand this thought, we end up at an understanding of maya. There is the 'human' world, which is filled with goals, uses, values, purposes, desires, and the like, all constructed with language; we draw material out of the 'natural' world in order to fulfill those human intentions. Only a human can see the human world — a deer cannot see the difference between concrete and rock; a bear does not distinguish between a house and a cave — and to this extent the human world is entirely illusory.

This isn't merely a matter of culture, though encountering a different culture can sometimes make the illusory aspect of the linguistic mind more obvious. We are embedded in this human world of language to such an extent that it is almost invisible to us. If we walk into a store we will see rows of objects all carefully constructed for particular tasks and purposes, neatly organized and labeled, but we won't necessarily recognize how much that construction, organization, and labeling are mediated and determined by language. A store catering to a different culture can disrupt that: objects will be labelled in a different language, and organized in different ways; some may have no discernible purpose to us at all. We are forced back towards that 'natural' state of seeing without the mediation of language.

The point here is that we live within a carefully cultivated illusion of sense, meaning, order, and purpose; we thrive when things around us have labels and values and obvious intents. In fact, it is extremely difficult to live outside of this carefully cultivated illusion, but the fact that this illusion is an essential part of human life does not make it any less of an illusion. We can exist as animals do in the 'natural' world, but part of being human entails entering into and participating in the collective illusion of the human world.

Comment: Was with you up until the, 'When a feature ...'  paragraph. I think from that point on it became 'non-sequitor' . You are making an interesting and relevant to the question, point; the tail end might need a little revision. Regards,

Comment: @CharlesMSaunders: Meh, yeah; not my best work. I was a bit distracted when I wrote it.  I'll clean it up tomorrow.

Comment: It seems to me that the question of illusion is not as to freedom from specific cultural fixations, but as to why any variability of perception should exist at all.

Comment: @CharlesMSaunders: edited: does that work better?

Comment: @exp8j: I've edited the answer to downplay the cultural aspect. tell me if this makes more sense to you.

Comment: @Ted Wrigley  You seem to suggest that an analysis of our human condition makes us aware of its insecure, arbitrary foundations. I agree that in many aspects this is true, but there are  strange exceptions. E.g. mathematical proofs seem to offer a sense of 
 "permanence" higher than, say, achievement of high societal status. So if we accept this "gradation of illusion", perhaps we have a tiny clue  as to its structure, which points away from an absurd and meaningless life, not for sentimental but for logical reasons.

Comment: @exp8j: I don't think you're going to find an example of a 'mathematical proof' in the 'natural' world. One has to be inculcated in the human illusion even to do something as simple as count, because one can't *count* unless one has linguistic representations of numbers. I'm more curious about your leap from 'illusory' to words like 'insecure', 'arbitrary', and 'meaningless'; where does that sentiment come from?

Comment: I think that mathematical theorems belong to the natural world
exactly like trees and winds do. 
Our human  thought is a natural phenomenon,
which, in a sense, lives within us and exhibits some strong tendecies
e.g. towards unification of diversity, followed by deconstruction
and unification on a more comprehensive level.
I mentioned mathematics as an example of this process,
but all creative pursuits essentially do the same.
Creative in the sense of approaching something
infinitely beautiful. This sums up a certain feeling.
Failure to do so leads to insecurity and lack of meaning.

Comment: @Ted Wrigley- Just bumped into a piece which seemed to reflect your piece on 'Illusion'. It's called, 'The Mirrors of Enigma', by Jorge Luis Borges. Regards,

Comment: @Ted Wrigley yes, thank you for this acutely perceptive perspective on our world of language as an  illusion. For me the recent posts or answers from Geoffry, J D, yourself and Conifold's response to the OP on the physics question all make me quite satisfied to be a SEP member. And beyond that remind that Richard Mason's,  (Univ. of Chicago), contention that no one philosophy is as 'wealthy' as all philosophies taken together.

Comment: That should have been Richard McKeon, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Though Indian philosophy is a made-up solution to life's problems like suffering, impermanence, difficulty in satisfying one's desires etc., this does not mean this is possible just by studying Indian philosophy.

When we reach higher classes we understand higher levels of truth. Though many of *the ideas* we studied in lower classes may be insignificant in higher classes, we never mock at the children in lower classes.  Similarly you can treat [dvaita, vishistadvaita and advaita](https://www.speakingtree.in/blog/dvaita-advaita-vishishtadvaitasimpli-fied) .

The Upanishads invoke to [awake and arise to get out of the hypnotized state of mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arise,_awake,_and_stop_not_till_the_goal_is_reached) ; never to take rest and read Indian philosophy believing this world is an illusion. If we place illusion at the topmost, we need not expect that it would be a made-up solution to what you called life's problems. If it were so, you had better discard this philosophy.  Again,

The following characteristics might be reason for the acceptability of that Indian philosophy.

1. It does not keep off other philosophies.
2. It is based on robust thought (including reasoning) rather than
   eminent personality.  So it never needs any propagation.
3. Different paths are designed for people of different temperaments.
4. Though it aims purification of mind, it is not concerned with mere
   mental exercise. Truth Realization (*sathya* [*darshan*](https://www.ananda.org/yogapedia/darshan/)) is possible while
   living.  So it does not wait for a posthumous life.

If you could find any of the above mentioned characteristics as defied, my personal opinion is that you could better seek similar or better philosophies than Indian philosophy according to your temperaments. [“Ekam Sat Vipra Bahudha Vadanti”](https://www.speakingtree.in/blog/ekam-sat-vipra-bahuda-vadanti) (The details in the link given by Swami Vishwananda would help you to ponder on superimposition.)

Collective illusion is occurring in our daily life.  The blue sky we see high above the earth is not there. Even though we all know very well that it is only an illusion, we always live under this collective illusion. I am saying so just to mention that an illusion can also be collective and it can be something that does not leave even a trace of illusion to the human world.

When questioning further, a true brilliant-seeker/aspirant would understand what we considered as fundamental is not fundamental;  we can go behind it to discover something more fundamental. Just ask yourself: When atom was first discovered, as its name indicates, it was treated as the fundamental particle. Is it so now? Did the modern science get the fundamental so far?  So, we can say what we 'experience' as more fundamental concepts or experiences, are founded on superimposition.  I don't think the reverse statement is rational. If 'illusion' in Indian philosophy is founded on more fundamental concepts or experiences, we must be compelled to say that the more fundamental concepts or experiences we say are more fundamental in all aspects. This is not true from another viewpoint.  Again, **see the plurality (duality) in the usage -- 'founded on more fundamental concepts or experiences'.  If you are asking the question in this order it can deny non-duality itself.  But if it were in the reverse order as I mentioned, no problem would arise**.

So, to be practical (*darshan*), the revere statement must be true.  That is,  **More fundamental concepts or experiences are founded on 'illusion'(superimposition) as viewed in Indian philosophy.**

I believe the aforesaid link would help you to understand the apt meaning of 'founded on superimposition'.

The great astonishment in a person while Truth realization is because of **the waking up** from the superimposition which we all believed as more fundamental experience till then.

Comment: From the text suggested by Swami Vishwananda and other sources, it seems that all we can say about the "foundations of illusion" is that "ignorance is beginingless". To my mind, this means that we can say nothing about its origin; only accept that ignorance exists. If you please, what is your understanding of this phrase?

Comment: @SonOfThought - Thank for this very straightforward depiction of the status and purpose of the concept of 'illuaion'  in the Indian philosophy. The piece on the 'atom' was most helpful. Regards,

Comment: @exp8j: "see a rope in a snake"--this is a wrong usage. When you see the rope you can't see the snake. When there is ignorance there is only ignorance. But when you realize the truth you can't see the snake (ignorance) there. I have made a few edits in my answer.  Please read it.

Comment: You seem to accept that total illusion exists without any need for further discussion. And that there is either total illusion or total truth resulting from a sudden waking up.I respect that view, but I am more into seeing gradations in our understanding. A "sudden waking up" is the result of gradual previous efforts.

Comment: @exp8j:Just think about watching a movie on the screen. We are aware of the screen only when the movie ends. Can we find any gradations in our understanding here in this daily life (up to the time when we are aware that it is only a screen)? How could be the gradual previous effort?

Comment: We are able to differentiate between a bare screen
and a screen with a movie played on it, because we have 
acquired this ability from previous experience.
Otherwise we could continue looking at the bare screen
as part of the movie. A baby at the cinema would do just that.

Comment: @exp8j: Yes. You have mentioned about our previous experience. We are aware of it only because of our previous experience. This is the case of cinema. In the case of life, we haven't any such previous experience yet.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. Is cinema outside life?

Comment: "Consciousness is the screen on which all the pictures come and go. The screen is real, the pictures are mere shadows on it." Read Ramana Maharshi. https://arunachala.org/sri-ramana-maharshi/teachings-of-ramana-maharshi/ You may follow Him.

Comment: Our attitudes are a bit different but I find your suggestions and excitement quite inspiring.

Comment: This might be a supplement to the above link https://www.davidgodman.org/be-as-you-are-excerpt/